# Problem with instance of object from library

Tags: python

I'm trying to create config.py in my libraries because I have in every script below code:

```
config = ""
try:
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    if (configFile is None) or (configFile == ""):
        configReadArrayLength = len(config.read(pathABSofScript + 'config.ini'))
    else:
        configReadArrayLength = len(config.read(configFile))
    if configReadArrayLength == 0:
        print("Script could not find configuration file.")
        exit(1)
except Exception as ex:
    print("An exception of typ {0} occurred in config parsing function. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting."
          .format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args))
    exit(1)

    def get_config_value(value):
try:
    return config['environment'][value]
except KeyError:
    return None
except Exception as config_value_exception:
    standard_logger_error(type(config_value_exception).__name__, config_value_exception.args)
```

And I don't want do duplicate code. So the steps which I have followed:

0) Structure looks like this:

```
/
scripts/
        somescript.py
        lib/
            config.py
```

1) In my somescript.py I have put:

```
sys.path.insert(0, /home/user/some/path/lib')
import config
```

2) config.py content:

```
import configparser


config = ""


def create_config_instance(path, file_name):
    try:
        global config
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        configReadArrayLength = len(config.read(path + file_name))
        if configReadArrayLength == 0:
            raise IOError("Cannot read config file")
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception("An exception of typ {0} occurred in config parsing function. Arguments:\n{1!r} exiting.".format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args))


def get_config_value(value):
    try:
        global config
        section = config['DEFAULT']['section_to_use']
        # return config[section][value]
        return "ELO"
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError
    except Exception as config_value_exception:
        # return str(type(config_value_exception).__name__, config_value_exception.args)
        raise Exception(config_value_exception)
```

3) Content of somescript.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import unittest
import os
import sys
import platform
sys.path.insert(0, '/scripts/lib')
import logger
import config


pathABSofScript = ""
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    pathABSofScript = str(os.path.realpath(__file__).rsplit('/', 1)[0]) + "/"
else:
    print("Unknown linux")
    exit(1)

# I'm creating instance of config.py object and passing there location of a file and file name
config_instance = config.create_config_instance(pathABSofScript, "config.ini")
# I'm trying to get value from config.ini
pathDBfile = config_instance.get_config_value("pathDBfile")
print(pathDBfile)

class TestDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And I'm facing this error:

```
File "./somescript.py", line 21, in <module>
pathDBfile = config_instance.get_config_value("pathDBfile")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_config_value'
```

Can someone give me a tip to resolve my problem?

Comment: One quick thing, in your `1)` part, it'd be a lot cleaner to do `from .lib import config` instead of the sys path append. You'd need to define an `__init__.py` file inside lib for it to work though.

Comment: This question is way too long to read entirely, but obviously the problem is that `config.create_config_instance` is not returning anything, which causes the problem. BTW, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)